# Does AVPlayer support both H-265 and DVR in iOS 10 or iOS 11?

Tags: objective-c, ios10, avplayer, ios11

Does AVPlayer support both H-265 and DVR (Digital Video Recording for Live stream) in iOS 10? If not, does it support both in new iOS 11?

Answer (score 1):

The AVPlayer on iOS 10 doesn't support HEVC(H.265). You can try yourself with an iOS 10 iPhone on these sample videos : https://x265.com/hevc-video-files

But there is some good news. During the 2017 WWDC, Apple announced the support of HEVC in iOS 11 (also in macOS High Sierra and tvOS 11).

If you want more detailed informations about it, you should check out the following WWDC videos :

- [Introducing HEIF and HEVC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/503/)

For DVR support, I have never heard of this kind of feature in iOS at all.